# Where can I find the selection of the decoys (stealthy addresses) when constructing a transaction?

Tags: ringct

When constructing a new transaction, I have reached the function cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp/construct_tx_with_tx_key() and I am trying to understand where the decoys came from? How and when are they selected?

Answer (score 1):

The fake outputs are selected by the wallet in the wallet2::get_outs function, in src/wallet/wallet2.cpp.

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp, currently starting at line [6411](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/fad88e18a9795b377676ad6f63c1772868e0d761/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L6411).